# DataStructure Stack

Tags: data-structures

What does a Push operation on a stack return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on the implementation.

Push doesn't usually return anything as it adds an item you supply to the stack. The corresponding Pop operation would remove the item from the top of the stack and return it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supposed to return anything. In .Net it's defined [as a void function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.push.aspx), for example.

Comment: what does it returns in Java?

Comment: It returns the object you just pushed: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on the stack implementation, I think. Some implementations might return nothing, others a boolean value, others still the stack object itself for chaining:

```
stack.push(element1).push(element2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others here on the return value being void. However, your implementation might include a counter to keep track of how many times elements were added to the particular object of Stack. It could be of interest to those that are greedy about code optimizations. It could help evaluate current stack implementation and fine tune the initial size allocation (if it's array-based), for any possible performance improvements based on how the module developed in the original system has evolved over a period of time.